# How to properly make an android HttpGet Request

Tags: android, django

I am trying to make a get request from android to a backend Django server. The exception is thrown every time I make the request, and the server does not show that it was contacted. How can I do this properly? Thanks.

Here is my attempt:

client side android:

```
try{

        URI website = new URI(URL);
        //Request to server
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet();
        httpget.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpget);
        Log.d("EXECUTED",response.toString());
    }catch (Exception ex){
        textView.setText("Fail");
    }
```

Server Side Django:

```
def app(request, id):
      context = RequestContext(request)

      fab_categories = Catagories.objects.all()

      return HttpResponse("worked")
```

As requested Here is the logcat:

```
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at com.companion.app.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:57)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-07 22:09:35.150: W/System.err(1624):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also I have added the appropriate permissions to the manifest.

Comment: What exception? "Exception" is too broad.. It could be you never reach the server, a bad port, a bad url, etc.. Show us your stacktrace

Comment: I meant the catch statement. It fails right after the Client.execute function. I added the logcat of the program. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there :) I'm developing a similar application, I followed this tutorial.

Sorry to just drop a link here, but it is pretty self explanatory and the code is very well documented.

[Android Hive TUTORIAL: HTTP](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/)

Ignore the title, look into the InboxActivity.java code

Comment: I actually just resolved the problem :). The issue was I was making the request from inside onCreate. I created an async class and then instantiated that from onCreate.